# "Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator" when using fromChangelogStream

Tags: apache-flink, savepoints, flink-table-api

I want to use the savepoint mechanism to move existing jobs from one version of Flink to another, by:

1. Stopping a job with a savepoint
2. Creating a new job from the savepoint, on the new version.

Until Flink 1.14 I have no problem, but in Flink 1.15.1, it fails. Even when not changing the version and staying in 1.15.1, it fails. I get this error, meaning that it could not map the state from the previous job to the new one because of one operator:

```
Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint hdfs://hdfs-name:8020/flink-savepoints/savepoint-046708-238e921f5e78. Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator d14a399e92154660771a806b90515d4c to the new program, because the operator is not available in the new program.
```

After investigation, the problematic operator corresponds to a `ChangelogNormalize` operator, that I do not explicitly create. It is generated because I use [`tableEnv.fromChangelogStream(stream, schema, ChangelogMode.upsert())`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/api/bridge/java/StreamTableEnvironment.html#fromChangelogStream-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream-org.apache.flink.table.api.Schema-org.apache.flink.table.connector.ChangelogMode-) (the upsert mode is important, other modes do not fail). The table created is passed to an SQL query using the SQL API, which generates something like:

```
ChangelogNormalize[8] -> Calc[9] -> TableToDataSteam -> [my_sql_transformation] -> [my_sink]
```

In previous versions of Flink this operator was always given the same uid so the state could match when starting from the savepoint. In Flink 1.15.1, a different uid is generated every time. I could not find a reliable way to set that uid manually. The only way I found was by going backwards from the transformation:

```
dataStream.getTransformation().getInputs().get(0).getInputs().get(0).getInputs().get(0).setUid("the_user_defined_id");
```

but I would expect to have a better way to do that.

Do you have any idea what I do wrong? Could it be a bug in Flink?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you create a ticket in https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK and post the link here?

Comment: Thanks, I've opened a ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening an issue on JIRA, it does seem to be a bug.

One workaround for now is to set `table.exec.legacy-transformation-uids` to `true`.

Comment: It has now been fixed in Flink 1.15.2: https://flink.apache.org/news/2022/08/25/release-1.15.2.html